# Uniswap V2 Router, Factory on Rinkeby testnet

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Is it possible to use Uniswap V2 router on rinkeby? What is the contract address of a router? i found only factory contract address ?

Answer (score 5):

The Uniswap V2 [router](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/) address is `'0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'` for all networks.

In the official documentation you can also find the [interface](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/#interface) to use the Router.

Comment: Can i use uniswap app with metamask on rinkeby to do some tests?

Comment: Yes. Go to https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap and connect to Rinkeby in Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

Everything remains the same for Uniswap V2 on testnets Rinkeby and Kovan (don't know about the others). It's only on Uniswap V1 where the addresses change.